# Matching a case when one element in a pair is Null

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I've got a dataset of laitutdes and longitudes. Unfortunately, some of the dataset was from when a time when lat/longs weren't constantly recorded. So I need to remove the invalid data before working with it.

I've already removed the cases with no lat/long at all, but I'm having trouble
with the cases where only one of the values are missing. Why this is the case in the original data, I'm not sure.

So I've used `Deletecases` on my original data,

```
DeleteCases[originaldata, {Null, Null}]
```

So now I have something like this:

```
mylist = 
 {{Null, 53.}, {-5.52167, 105.308}, {-6.70833, 39.665}, {-1., 116.}, 
  {5.58333, 97.0833}, {-6.25117, 108.446}, {22.1783, 91.7767}};
```

How would I delete any tuples with either value `Null`?

Comment: Try: `DeleteCases[mylist, {Null, _} | {_, Null}]`. This will also take care of the case where both entries are `Null` so you only have to use `DeleteCases` once.

Comment: Since your entries appear to be all `Real` you can simply use `Cases[mylist, {_Real, _Real}]`

Comment: {_Real, _Real} did it for me. I was attempting to use {_NumericQ, _NumericQ} which obviously didn't work.

Comment: You can use `NumericQ` but be aware that you'll have to put `?` before it. i.e. `{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RunnyKine's comment written up as a answer.

```
DeleteCases[mylist, {Null, _} | {_, Null}].
```

This will also take care of the case where both entries are `Null`, so you only have to use `DeleteCases` once.

However, since your entries appear to be all reals, you might use

```
Cases[mylist, {_Real, _Real}
```

But if some of your numeric values don't have head real, then

```
Cases[mylist, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Also consider:

```
DeleteCases[mylist, {___, Null, ___}]
```

Or:

```
Select[mylist, FreeQ[Null]]  (* v10 operator syntax *)
```